# PanGestureHandler Expected `onGestureHandlerEvent` listener to be a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

Using `PanGestureHandler` from `react-native-gesture-handler` with `react-native-reanimated` with `useAnimatedGestureHandler` throws this error.

> Expected `onGestureHandlerEvent` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type

These are the components being rendered,

```
<View style={[styles.center]}>
  <Text style={{color: "#555", fontSize:16, marginTop: 120, marginBottom: 70, width: 250, margin: 'auto'}}>Works on the web but throws an error on iOS.</Text>

  <Animated.View style={[styles.box, styles.center, animatedStyle]}>
    <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
      <Text style={{color: "#444", fontWeight:'bold', padding: 16,}}>Drag me around</Text>
    </PanGestureHandler>
  </Animated.View>
</View>;
```

Snack here, https://snack.expo.dev/4Mp-PfXPU

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This comment](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1506#issuecomment-860684310) on GitHub points in the correct direction.

Though not specified in the docs, but can be inferred from the examples... `PanGestureHandler` requires an animated component child inside `<PanGestureHandler ...>`. (Such as `<Animated.View ...>`)

So `<Animated.View ...>...</Animated.View>`, or some other animated component, needs to be inside `<PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>`.

```
<PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.box, styles.center, animatedStyle]}>
      <Text style={{color: "#444", fontWeight:'bold', padding: 16,}}>Drag me around</Text>
  </Animated.View>
</PanGestureHandler>
```

Here's a working snack,

https://snack.expo.dev/ZRr6t24Hv